# SharePoint Authentication with Azure AD (no ACS available)

Tags: 2013, azure, azure-ad

We want to use SharePoint On-premise on Azure VMs. The users are synced to Azure AD.

I've read many articles about authenticating this users via Azure Access Control Services, but ACS isn't available at the new German Datacenters.

Does anybody have an idea for authenticating these users (a companion app maybe? Some custom code?)

Comment: Why not just use Active Directory? What benefits do you hope to gain when it requires AD already?

Comment: The customer has no active connection to azure (no P2S or S2S VPN). So my only option here is to synchronize them to Azure AD (which doesn't need a VPN). So I have no chance to build a RODC or something similar in Azure.

Comment: Yeah, ACS is required to configure that trust with Azure. An S2S VPN should be pretty easy to configure... though I generally don't do SharePoint on Azure since you can't install WAC or OOS due to licensing restrictions.

Comment: Please check this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/using-azure-ad-for-sharepoint-server-authentication